# compare vertical distance from the top of an element and scroll distance from top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with my js codes,I want to compare vertical distance from top of an element with scroll distance and if scroll distance is more than distance from the top of an element fixed the position of div with "thead" id in top of the page.

my js code :

```
var distance = $("#thead").offset().top;
var wdistance = $(window).scrollTop();
if (wdistance > distance) {
 alert('this is test');
};
```

demo in

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkafiyan/HmFW7/2/)

Comment: Your fiddle didn't come through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a scroll handler:

```
var distance = $("#thead").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var wdistance = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (wdistance > distance) {
        alert('this is test');
    };
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HmFW7/3/)

Comment: another question, I want to say when this "if" is correct then position of div with "thead" id become fixed on top of the other tables when scrolling the page how can I write it?

Comment: @mimi Ask another question for that.